# Query execution time doesn't make sense: Individual CTEs run (the second with pre-generated data) in less than a second, but over an hour when chained

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a series of CTE's that each on their own (when using pre-generated data) execute in under a second, that when chained as follows execute in over an hour:

`Segments->UnstructuredJobsPre->UnstructuredJobs->Jobs`

Running everything up to `Jobs`, without `Jobs` itself, is fine; running `Jobs` on its own, with exactly the data generated from the previous, is fine; and these two permutations run in under a second each; but together they're well over an hour.

Additionally, running `[pre-generated]->UnstructuredJobs->Jobs` also takes less than a second or two; but running `[pregenerated]->UnstructuredJobsPre->UnstructuredJobs->Jobs` takes a long time as well, leading me to believe it's some kind of interaction between `UJP` and `Jobs`.

Finally, I have a parallel query beginning from the same point and following analogous logic that runs perfectly, start to finish.

The main query relies on an API to get the data and I'm limited in what I can post, so what follows is, in order, the whole query, the parallel query and the pre-generated Jobs query. I'm happy to post the query plans as well, but both are well over the character count in and of themselves. If there's any easy way to do this, I'll put them up right away.

Let me know if you have any ideas! I am at a complete loss...

Whole query:

```sql
DECLARE @Dwg TABLE (Num VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Dwg (Num) VALUES
    ('I03SOV3E215921C')

; WITH Segments AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Dwg.Num 'Segment'
        , MI.Item 'Assembly'
        , Mrp.Job
    FROM @Dwg Dwg
    INNER JOIN vgMfiItems MI ON Dwg.Num = MI.DrawingNumber
    INNER JOIN Mrpres Mrp ON MI.Item = Mrp.Item
    INNER JOIN vgJcoWorkOrder WO ON Mrp.Job = WO.Job
    WHERE
        WO.WorkOrderStatus <> 'CLOSED'
        AND WO.WorkOrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED'
)
, UnstructuredJobsPre AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        S.Segment
        , S.Job 'Root'
        , WOT.TreeviewOrder
        , WOT.TreeViewOrderParent
        , WOT.ChildValue 'Child'
        , WOT.ChildId
        , WOT.LineLevel
    FROM Segments S
    CROSS APPLY fnJcoWorkOrderTreeView(S.Job) WOT
)
, UnstructuredJobs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UJ.Segment
        , UJ.Root
        , UJ.TreeviewOrder
        , UJ.Child
        , MrpR.Qte_Ass 'Qty'
        , CASE WHEN UJP.LineLevel > 5
            THEN UJP.TreeViewOrderParent
            ELSE UJ.TreeViewOrderParent
        END 'TreeViewOrderParent'
        , UJ.LineLevel
        , UJ.WOFlag
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            UJP.Segment
            , UJP.Root
            , UJP.TreeviewOrder
            , UJP.TreeViewOrderParent
            , CASE WHEN UJP.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                THEN UJP.Child
                ELSE WO.Item
            END 'Child'
            , UJP.ChildId
            , UJP.LineLevel
            , CASE WHEN UJP.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END 'WOFlag'
        FROM UnstructuredJobsPre UJP
        LEFT JOIN vgJcoWorkOrder WO ON UJP.Child = WO.WorkOrder
        WHERE
            UJP.LineLevel = 5 OR UJP.LineLevel > 5 AND (UJP.LineLevel + 1) % 3 = 0
            AND (
                UJP.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                OR UJP.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
                OR UJP.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
            )
    ) UJ
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Pre.Root
            , Pre.TreeviewOrder
            , Pre.TreeViewOrderParent
            , Pre.Child
            , Pre.ChildId
            , Pre.LineLevel
        FROM UnstructuredJobsPre Pre
        WHERE Pre.LineLevel > 5 AND (Pre.LineLevel + 2) % 3 = 0
    ) UJP
        ON UJ.Root = UJP.Root
        AND UJ.TreeViewOrderParent = UJP.TreeviewOrder
    INNER JOIN vgMRPAllocations MrpA
        ON UJ.Root = MrpA.JobCode
        AND UJ.ChildId = MrpA.Link
    INNER JOIN Mrpres MrpR
        ON UJ.Root = MrpR.Job
        AND UJ.Child = MrpR.Item
    WHERE
        MrpA.IsActive = 1
)
, Jobs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UJ.Segment
        , UJ.Root
        , UJ.TreeviewOrder
        , CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 'Branch'
        , UJ.Child
        , UJ.Qty
        , UJ.WOFlag
    FROM UnstructuredJobs UJ
    WHERE
        UJ.LineLevel = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        J.Segment
        , J.Root
        , UJ.TreeviewOrder
        , CASE WHEN J.Branch IS NULL
            THEN J.Child
            ELSE J.Branch + '>' + J.Child
        END 'Branch'
        , UJ.Child
        , UJ.Qty
        , UJ.WOFlag
    FROM Jobs J
    INNER JOIN UnstructuredJobs UJ
        ON J.Root = UJ.Root
        AND J.TreeviewOrder = UJ.TreeViewOrderParent
)
SELECT * FROM Jobs
```

Jobs query:

```sql
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Segment VARCHAR(MAX), [Root] VARCHAR(MAX), Child VARCHAR(MAX), Qty FLOAT, TreeviewOrder VARCHAR(MAX), TreeViewOrderParent VARCHAR(MAX), LineLevel INTEGER, WOFlag INTEGER)
INSERT INTO @Temp (Segment, [Root], Child, Qty, TreeviewOrder, TreeViewOrderParent, LineLevel, WOFlag) VALUES
    ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '318-0088', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.007', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '352-0051', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.008', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '174-0332', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.009', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '172-0178', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.010', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '164-0252', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.011', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '164-0251', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.012', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '267-0061', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.013', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '148-0454', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.014', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '171-0095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.015', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '197-0105', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.016', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '355-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.017', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '354-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.018', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '180-0052', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.019', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '162-0269', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.020', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '287-0009', '10', '001.002.003.001.005.021', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '108-1095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.022', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '254-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.023', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '254-0003', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.024', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '171-0092', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.025', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '164-0239', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '165-0614', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '358-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '328-0100', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '153-0599', '0.5', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '116-0030', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '197-0099', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.032', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '165-0607', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.033', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '328-0098', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.034', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '182-0700', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.035', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41114', '155-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.036', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '318-0088', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.001', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '352-0051', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.002', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '174-0332', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.003', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '172-0178', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.004', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '164-0252', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.005', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '164-0251', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.006', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '153-0599', '0.5', '001.002.003.001.005.007', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '267-0061', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.008', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '148-0454', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.009', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '171-0095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.010', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '197-0105', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.011', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '355-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.012', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '354-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.013', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '180-0052', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.014', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '162-0269', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.015', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '287-0009', '10', '001.002.003.001.005.016', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '108-1095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.017', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '254-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.018', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '254-0003', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.019', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '171-0092', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.020', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '164-0239', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.021', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '165-0614', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.022', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '328-0100', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.023', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '116-0030', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.025', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '197-0099', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '165-0607', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '328-0098', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '182-0700', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '155-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '358-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41118', '153-0702', '2.375', '001.002.003.001.005.031.006.001.008.006', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '318-0088', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.001', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '352-0051', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.002', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '174-0332', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.003', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '172-0178', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.004', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '164-0252', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.005', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '164-0251', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.006', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0599', '0.5', '001.002.003.001.005.007', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '267-0061', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.008', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '197-0105', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.009', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '355-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.010', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '354-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.011', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '287-0009', '10', '001.002.003.001.005.012', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '254-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.013', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '254-0003', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.014', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '171-0092', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.015', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '164-0239', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.016', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '165-0614', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.017', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '328-0100', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.018', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '116-0030', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.020', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '197-0099', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.021', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '165-0607', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.022', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '328-0098', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.023', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '182-0700', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.024', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '155-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.025', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '148-0454', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0718', '2.5', '001.002.003.001.005.026.006.001.008.004', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0718', '7', '001.002.003.001.005.026.006.001.008.004', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '171-0095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0718', '2.5', '001.002.003.001.005.027.006.001.008.005', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0718', '7', '001.002.003.001.005.027.006.001.008.005', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '180-0052', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0469', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.028.006.001.008.005', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '162-0269', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0705', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.029.006.001.008.004', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '108-1095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '169-0228', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.030.006.001.008.010', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '358-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41119', '153-0702', '2.375', '001.002.003.001.005.031.006.001.008.006', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '318-0088', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.001', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '352-0051', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.002', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '174-0332', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.003', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '172-0178', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.004', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '164-0252', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.005', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '164-0251', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.006', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '153-0599', '0.5', '001.002.003.001.005.007', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '197-0099', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.008', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '267-0061', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.009', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '148-0454', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.010', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '171-0095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.011', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '197-0105', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.012', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '355-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.013', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '354-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.014', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '180-0052', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.015', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '287-0009', '10', '001.002.003.001.005.016', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '108-1095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.017', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '254-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.018', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '254-0003', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.019', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '171-0092', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.020', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '164-0239', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.021', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '165-0614', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.022', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '358-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.023', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '328-0100', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.024', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '116-0030', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '165-0607', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '328-0098', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '182-0700', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '155-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '162-0269', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.032', '001.002.003.001', '5', '1')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41121', '153-0705', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.032.006.001.008.004', '001.002.003.001.005.032', '8', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '174-0332', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.007', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '172-0178', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.008', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '164-0252', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.009', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '164-0251', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.010', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '318-0088', '2', '001.002.003.001.005.012', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '352-0051', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.013', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '267-0061', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.014', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '148-0454', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.015', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '171-0095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.016', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '197-0105', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.017', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '355-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.018', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '354-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.019', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '180-0052', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.020', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '162-0269', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.021', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '287-0009', '10', '001.002.003.001.005.022', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '108-1095', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.023', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '254-0002', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.024', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '254-0003', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.025', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '171-0092', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.026', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '164-0239', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.027', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '165-0614', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.028', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '358-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.029', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '328-0100', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.030', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '153-0599', '0.5', '001.002.003.001.005.031', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '116-0030', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.032', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '197-0099', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.033', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '165-0607', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.034', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '328-0098', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.035', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '182-0700', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.036', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')
    , ('I03SOV3E215921C', '41123', '155-0005', '1', '001.002.003.001.005.037', '001.002.003.001', '5', '0')

; WITH Jobs AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UJ.Segment
        , UJ.Root
        , UJ.TreeviewOrder
        , CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 'Branch'
        , UJ.Child
        , UJ.Qty
        , UJ.WOFlag
    FROM @Temp UJ
    WHERE
        UJ.LineLevel = 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        J.Segment
        , J.Root
        , UJ.TreeviewOrder
        , CASE WHEN J.Branch IS NULL
            THEN J.Child
            ELSE J.Branch + '>' + J.Child
        END 'Branch'
        , UJ.Child
        , UJ.Qty
        , UJ.WOFlag
    FROM Jobs J
    INNER JOIN @Temp UJ
        ON J.Root = UJ.Root
        AND J.TreeviewOrder = UJ.TreeViewOrderParent
)
SELECT * FROM Jobs
```

Parallel query:

```sql
DECLARE @Dwg TABLE (Num VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Dwg (Num) VALUES
    ('I03SOV3E215921C')


; WITH Segments AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Dwg.Num 'Segment'
        , MI.Item 'Assembly'
        , Mrp.Job
    FROM @Dwg Dwg
    INNER JOIN vgMfiItems MI ON Dwg.Num = MI.DrawingNumber
    INNER JOIN Mrpres Mrp ON MI.Item = Mrp.Item
    INNER JOIN vgJcoWorkOrder WO ON Mrp.Job = WO.Job
    WHERE
        WO.WorkOrderStatus <> 'CLOSED'
        AND WO.WorkOrderStatus <> 'CANCELLED'
)
, UnstructuredBom AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        S.Segment
        , S.Assembly
        , Bom.TreeViewLevel
        , REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Bom.TreeViewLevel), 6, LEN(Bom.TreeViewLevel))) 'TreeViewLevelParent'
        , Bom.Child
        , Bom.ItemQuantityPerAssembly 'Qty'
        , Bom.ComponentLevel
    FROM Segments S
    CROSS APPLY fnGetBomExplodeTable(S.Assembly, NULL, default, default) Bom
    WHERE
        Bom.ComponentLevel > 0
        AND Bom.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)
, Assemblies AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UBom.Segment
        , UBom.Assembly 'Root'
        , UBom.TreeViewLevel
        , CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 'Branch'
        , UBom.Child
        , UBom.Qty
    FROM UnstructuredBom UBom
    WHERE
        UBom.ComponentLevel = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        A.Segment
        , A.Root
        , UBom.TreeViewLevel
        , CASE WHEN A.Branch IS NULL
            THEN A.Child
            ELSE A.Branch + '>' + A.Child
        END 'Branch'
        , UBom.Child
        , UBom.Qty
    FROM Assemblies A
    INNER JOIN UnstructuredBom UBom
        ON A.Root = UBom.Assembly
        AND A.TreeViewLevel = UBom.TreeViewLevelParent
)
SELECT * FROM Assemblies
```

Comment: Pet peeve: [The semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated. Not terminating your statements properly is deprecated, so you should really try to get into the habit of properly terminating your statements now, so that your code doesn't break if the change is ever forced through.

Comment: Is there a reason you dump `DISTINCT` at the start of *every* statement? That alone won't be good for performance, and it doesn't make sense in a lot of places. For example you use `DISTINCT` in `UnstructuredBom`, and then in `Assemblies ` request the `DISTINCT` rows from that CTE; you've already defined that data set as `DISTINCT` so *why* are you asking SQL Server to do such an expensive operation a second time?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the advice. I think I was just being overly cautious (I'm still pretty new to SQL), but I can appreciate the point. I'll try to be more judicious about it going forward. And the same for the semi-colons. I'll look deeper into the article you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Is `Num` also likely to be more than 8,000 characters? If so, then it's not a good candidate for a `JOIN`. If it isn't, why is it defined a `MAX`, which means you're stating that it's likely to be more than 8,000 characters (for a `varchar`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. David Brown helped me find the answer I originally asked the question for, but I've taken into account everything you've suggested as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTEs and subqueries are compiled into one big plan, sometimes not a good one.  So either

1. optimize the query to make the plan better.  The obvious first step here is to replace

```
    INSERT INTO @Dwg (Num) VALUES
        ('I03SOV3E215921C')
```

with a temp table with a clustered index on Num, as table variables don't have statistics.

2. Materialize the partial result by loading temp tables, and referencing them in your larger query.  EG

```
    INSERT INTO #UnstructuredBOM (...)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        S.Segment
        , S.Assembly
        , Bom.TreeViewLevel
        , REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Bom.TreeViewLevel), 6, LEN(Bom.TreeViewLevel))) 'TreeViewLevelParent'
        , Bom.Child
        , Bom.ItemQuantityPerAssembly 'Qty'
        , Bom.ComponentLevel
    FROM Segments S
    CROSS APPLY fnGetBomExplodeTable(S.Assembly, NULL, default, default) Bom
    WHERE
        Bom.ComponentLevel > 0
        AND Bom.Child LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Then

```
, UnstructuredBom AS ( select * from #UnstructuredBOM )
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that today if I can find the time. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks

Comment: Also, maybe you have a better strategy for this, but the reason for that first table variable is to leave myself room for interfacing with an Excel VBA macro, that'll allow my coworkers to simply enter those values into the first column, and then hit a button to refresh the query. It's not ideal as I have it now, because it requires converting the entire query into a series of strings that are concatenated and fed into wherever it is the query lives already in Excel.